# Double set difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B \subset X$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. What is $A \setminus (A \setminus B)$? Since $A,B$ are disjoint, $A \setminus B = A$, whence $A \setminus (A \setminus B) = A \setminus A$.  Now what is this set? It's the set of elements of $A$ that are not elements of $A$. Well, there are no such elements in $A$, right? Thus $A \setminus A = \emptyset$.

Is this correct? This is related to an exercise (my first ever) in measure theory, if you're wondering where this question could possibly come from.

Comment: A \ A means the set of elements that are in A AND not in A, meaning, exactly as you mentioned, that it's the empty set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is just fine. You can show more generally that $A\setminus(A\setminus B)=A\cap B$. Intuitively this should be clear: $B$ splits $A$ into the disjoint pieces $A\setminus B$ and $A\cap B$, which are relative complements of each other in $A$.